# Wrong value when using PHP with the Views module

Tags: views

I have a float field, and I just want to print this field in a PHP field. I am using this code.

```
print $row->title; // It prints the same value.
print $row->field_pa_total; // It prints the wrong value; the field value is 5000, but the printed value is 40.
```

How do I print the field value?

Comment: Please specify what Drupal and Views versions you are using.

Answer (score 2):

`print_r($row);` should give you the structure of the row and tell you the names of the various fields and values etc.

Comment: Just complementing for the OPs benefit, the object attribute is named more like the schema, so it would be $row->field_pa_total_value or $row->field_pa_total['und'][0]['value'] or something like that

Comment: i tried    print_r($row) the result is:   
stdClass Object ( [title] => 1 [title_1] => ???? [field_pi_lastname] => 146 [field_pi_father] => 146 [field_bt_address] => 148 [field_bt_work] => 148 [field_bt_hospital] => 148 [field_bt_money] => 148 [field_bt_active] => 148 [field_bt_total] => 148 [field_pa_total] => 151 [php] => [expression] => )